# How to Detect IE Version on Vista and Above

Tags: c#, windows, internet-explorer, detection

I would like to detect what version IE is running on Vista and above (I am developing on 7). I currently use WMI on XP, but it appears that this is no more. I have searched for an answer and so far I have found the following solutions:

```
Using System.Windows.Forms
WebBrowser wb = new WebBrowser;
wb.Version;

SELECT path,filename,extension,version FROM CIM_DataFile WHERE path="\\Program Files\\Internet Explorer\\" AND filename="iexplore" AND extension="exe" AND version>"8.0"

And there is probably a way of looking up in the registry.
```

Is there must a more elegant solution to this?

Comment: why can't you rely on wb.Version to get the version? or am i missing something in your question?

Comment: I dont know, is this recommended way of doing it?

Comment: <confused>When you have a property satisfying your need, why not use it? <confused>

Comment: I could use the WMI method given above and it would give me the right answer, I also could just check the registry, but both of those methods dont seem to me to be the correct/best way of doing it, I am after a more robust solution, is the WebBrowser class the answer or is there an other way?